# How to run script before the network configuration?

Tags: linux, systemd

The unit file for that is supposed to be like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=@CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY@

Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/sbin/my-script.sh

RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It's according to http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

> Services that want to be run before the network is configured should place Before=network-pre.target and also set Wants=network-pre.target to pull it in.

But it stops the networking service from running at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229048/how-to-start-a-systemd-service-before-networking-starts

Answer (score 3):

This what worked for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=@CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY@

Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/sbin/my-script.sh

RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```